# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads' in TwitterAPI call (iterating over tweets)?

Tags: python, twitter

When running the sample code on TwitterAPI page  [here](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) , I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Cloud/Dropbox/Coding/Python/EUR - BigData & Analytics/Workshops/Tutorial 2/twitter_query_scraper_revisited.py", line 76, in <module>
    for tweet in tweet_sequence:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 116, in __iter__
    for item in self.get_iterator():
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 113, in     get_iterator
    return RestIterator(self.response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 139, in __init__
    resp = response.json()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 741, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

I tried running through the various code, but I've been unable to solve it. 
This is the code I'm running:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

r = api.request('search/tweets', {'q':'pizza'})
for item in r.get_iterator():
    print item
```

I'm running the latest version of TwitterAPI (2.1.13), requests 2.2.1 and am running Python 3.3.4 on Windows 8.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You most likely have a *local* module `json.py` or directory called `json` which Python deems a namespace package. What does `import json; print(json.__file__)` print?

Comment: It prints 'C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py', I've been looking for this but I can't seem to find any alternative files called json on my system or in the Python paths?

Comment: But that module *has* a `json.dumps()`; are you sure you are running it with the same interpreter?

Comment: I'm as surprised as you are. I'm running the import json; print(json.__file__) in the same script as the for loop with the tweets (utilizing PyCharm). I disabled my other interpreter (2.7) in PyCharm and c:\python33\;c:\python33\scripts\ are the only python references in my path variable. What else could I do to validate it's the same interpreter?

Comment: One note, I did find a json.py in the Django package folder as well, could this cause it? EDIT: doh, that's actually in my python27 folder, not referenced to anywhere.

Comment: The one in Django is namespaced; it wouldn't be imported by `requests`. Do you feel up to stepping in with a debugger and inspecting `json` at the point of the exception?

Comment: I have no experience in debugging, but am more than willing to learn, could you provide a few pointers as for how I'd go about this? The PyCharm debugger points me to the 'def json(self, **kwargs)' piece of the models.py module of site-packages/requests/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51548/discussion-between-mv1990-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't assist you more directly; glad you solved the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `json` module that masks the standard library module, and it is imported instead.

Since your own `json` module has no `loads()` function, the `request` library trips up.

You can find what file this is by running:

```
import json
print(json.__file__)
```

Rename that module to something else.

Comment: I conducted a reinstall (via WinPython) and it now works correctly. Accepting as answer as it explains what causes the error.